# Instantiating a non-static Java Inner Class from JRuby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, inner-classes

So given the following java class:

```
class Outer
{
  private int x;
  public Outer(int x) { this.x = x; }
  public class Inner
  {
    private int y;
    public Inner(int y) { this.y = y; }
    public int sum() { return x + y; }
  }
}
```

I can create an instance of the inner class from Java in the following manner:

```
Outer o = new Outer(1);
Outer.Inner i = o.new Inner(2);
```

However, I can't seem how to do the same from JRuby

```
#!/usr/bin/env jruby
require 'java'
java_import 'Outer'

o = Outer.new(1);
i = o.Inner.new(2); #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `Inner' for #<Outer...>
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
i = Outer::Inner.new(o,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

From what can be seen in [this discussion](http://markmail.org/message/go53w4hge4gczjji), you'll have to do `Outer:Inner.new(o, 2)`